# where to find good exercise about Eigenvalue and determinant and scalar product

Tags: reference-request, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, determinant, scalar-fields

where  to  find   good exercise about  Eigenvalue and  determinant  and scalar product , exercise   in which  i  use all the  possible varities?

Comment: You can check Axler's great book Linear Algebra Done Right: http://www.springer.com/us/book/9783319110790

Comment: I liked David C. Lay's "Linear algebra and its applications". Although it has gotten a few new editions since I used it, so I don't know how it is now.

Answer (score 1):

Try Paul Halmos' *Linear Algebra problem book*.